# i have yii encoded string i want convert in array with key and value

Tags: php, yii

string is : {"4":"50","3":"80"}

i want output like below:

> Array (
>       [4] => 50
>       [3] => 80 )

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json_ddecode

```
 myArray = json_decode($myJsonString); 


 myArray = json_decode('{"4":"50","3":"80"}');
```